# intercalar registro en PHP y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

amigos, en una tabla mysql, tengo un campo llamado 'Orden' que indica el orden el que aparecerán los registros en un informe..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, necesito renumerar el campo orden, desde el numero que le indico, es decir, que si inicio el el numero de Orden 2, este, deberia pasar a ser 3, el 3 debería pasar a cuatro, y asi hasta el final de la tabla...

tengo esto, que evidentemente no funciona, aunque parecía una bonita opción.

```
$primero=2;// numero de Orden insertado renumerar a partir de aquí.
$presupuesto=169;
        $ult=mysql_query("SELECT max(Orden) as Orden FROM presupuestos WHERE NPresupuesto=169");
        while($rowtr = mysql_fetch_array($ult))
         {
           $ultimo=$rowtr['Orden']; // obtengo el ultimo numero de orden...


         }
    
       for($a=$primero;$a<=$ultimo;$a++){
         $b=$a+1;
          $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE presupuestos SET Orden=".$b." WHERE NPresupuesto=169"." AND Orden=".$a);
          
       
        
       }
```

alguna sugerencia ????

Gracias como siempre...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicar directamente la siguiente consulta en la base de datos:
Si el tipo de datos de la columna 'Orden' es INT:

```
UPDATE tu-tabla SET Orden = orden + 1
```

Si el tipo de datos es VARCHAR:

```
UPDATE tu-tabla SET Orden = CAST(Orden AS SIGNED) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve...

```
$a=1;               // si queremos empezar a renumerar desde el número 2
$presupuesto=159;   // lineas de presupuesto sobre el que se actúa.

 "UPDATE presupuestos SET Orden=Orden -1 WHERE NPresupuesto=".$presupuesto." And Orden >".$a." ORDER by Orden ASC"
```